# echo huge text giving arument list too long error

Tags: bash, arguments

Struggling with outputting huge text (around 500 KB) to a file on linux. Text contains spaces, special characters and other.... Getting error /bin/sh : argument list too long

```
#!/bin/bash
txt="---huge text separated by line and containing special characters---"
echo $txt
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
txt="---huge text separated by line and containing special characters---"
echo $txt >> filename.txt
```

Comment: Are there any backticks (`\``) or `$(` among those _special characters_?

Comment: How are you running that script? The error suggests it's interpreted by sh instead of bash or that somehow running that script causes /bin/sh to be executed.

Comment: What is the source of the huge text? Avoid to process it as shell arguments or feed the script with xargs!

Answer (score 1):

a workaround to avoid escaping " and ' , keep your output readable when viewing script is this : 
    **`cat >output <<textmarker`**
-construct 
Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat >filename.txt <<EOT
Your output-text starts here
Every new line or tab  will be on the output too
  "text0" 'text1'  echo "Hello" 
  #Any other even huge text   //
\n But Dollarsign and backslash have to be escaped 
For example \$ and \\
your output-text ends with this marker, which had to be on a newline without whitespace
EOT
```

Comment: Use `<<\EOF` if you don't want to have to escape every `$`, `\`` and backslash.

Comment: I removed special characters, newlines, white spaces and other characters. Now I am just having alphanumeric characters of total selection greater than 131052.. ....Still getting error /bin/sh : argument list too long
[code]
    #!/bin/bash
    txt="---huge text with total characters length 131053---"
[/code]

Comment: Ok, I figured out why this is happening. Size of command buffer in my system is 131072. When total text on input console is exceeding this limit then its giving argument list too long error. How I can increase this command buffer size?